# How to access web browser's (Web APIs) Console API types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, console.log, webapi

I'm writing a custom logger composable function which uses `console[logLevel]()` function to log messages when running dev build, and uses an external logging service when running production build.

**Is there a way to access [Console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console_API)'s type interface, like the type for `logLevel`, in TypeScript? Or do I need to create a custom type for it?**

Comment: Do you mean define the type for the `logLevel`?

Comment: Yes, I have already defined it as a custom enum type, but if possible I'd like to use some official or ready-made implementation of Web API's specification as type interface.

Comment: Is this the thing you need? `type LogAPI = keyof Console;`

Comment: That gives type of Console, but it includes all the methods included, where as log levels are just a subset of the methods included...